# How writing text onto specific place [Opal]

Tags: javascript, opalrb

I need write static web page with simple data.
In form i have data from user and in tag
`<div id="prog">` my output
How using Opal writing string into specyfic place?

```
<div id="prog">
</div><script type="text/javascript">
<div id="prog">
</div>
</script>
pp = document.getElementById("prog").innerHTML = Opal.main()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on your sample code, you just need to make `Opal.main()` return a string

```
def main
  # logic
  return str
end
```

But I think that what you really want is use opal-jquery or opal-browser, I don't have much experience with the later, so here's a simple example of opal-jquery (of what I understood you were asking)

```
Document.ready? 
  Element["form"].on(:submit) do
    Element["#prog].text = Element["#input-id"].value
  end
end
```